# Laravel 5.2 checkbox redirect withInput shows error - expects parameter 1 to be string array given

Tags: laravel, redirect, checkbox, laravel-5, laravel-blade

```
{!!Form::checkbox($name->key.'[]',$checkbox->value,(isset($result[$name->key])?in_array($checkbox->value,$result[$name->key]):''))!!}
```

Checkbox validation, db checkbox insertion as comma seperated, and then pre populate works fine. But my issue is when i redirect errors with input, it shows error - parameter 1 to be string array given.Then I remove withInput, it does not show any errors, but the checkbox selected not prepopulated.

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validateResult)->withInput($request->all());
```

[image]

Please help, is there any other option to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Problem is with: `in_array($checkbox->value,$result[$name->key])` so You should dump `$result[$name->key]` to check why it's a string.

Comment: I have removed the 3rd parameter in checkbox - (isset($result[$name->key])?in_array($checkbox->value,$result[$name->key]):'') and then check, but it shows the same error..

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of the error. Please check this. Thanks.